# how to exclude admin page from add_rewrite_rule in wordpress

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to add the following rewrite rules:

```
add_rewrite_rule('([A-Za-z0-9])/([A-Za-z0-9])', 'index.php/product?subcategory=$1&product=$2', 'top');

add_rewrite_rule('([A-Za-z0-9])', 'index.php/categories/?cat=$1', 'top');
```

The problem is that its affecting the admin page leading into an internal server error.

After the rules has been flushed the `.htaccess` file has added the rules above into the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9])/([A-Za-z0-9]) /wordpress/index.php/product/?subcategory=$1&product=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]) /wordpress/index.php/categories/?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So something like:

```
<domain>/GameConsoles/Nintendo3ds
<domain>/GameConsoles
```

But the problem is that the rules that I have set seems to be matching in the admin.

What am I doing wrong here? And with regards to SEO best practices should I be doing it this way or is it better to use something like:

```
<domain>/product/Nintendo3ds
<domain>/category/GameConsole
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    add_rewrite_rule('([A-Za-z0-9])/([A-Za-z0-9])', 'index.php/product?subcategory=$1&product=$2', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('([A-Za-z0-9])', 'index.php/categories/?cat=$1', 'top');
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?